# Does taking dual of a boolean expression also result in its complement?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I was revisiting XOR and XNOR and the form of their different equations.

XOR = A ⊕ B = A'B + AB'

I took the dual of it:

Dual of XOR
= (A'+B) (A + B')
= AA' + AB + A'B' + BB'
= AB + A'B'

This is exactly the boolean expression for XNOR.

Similarly...

XNOR =  A ⊙ B = AB + A'B'

Dual of XNOR
= (A + B)(A' + B')
= AA' + AB' + A'B + BB'
= AB' + A'B

Which is exactly the boolean expression for XOR.

Since XOR and XNOR are complements of each other, does taking the dual of a boolean expression also have the effect of its taking complement?

Or is it just coincidence that the dual of XOR is XNOR and vice versa?

Just to add that I kind of knew that duals and complements may not always be the same. For example, the complement of A+B is A’B’ and its dual is AB. But then I am bit surprised how the dual of XOR is XNOR and vice versa. I have been through various texts but no one pointed out that.

Is it mere coincidence or there is some pattern behind it? I mean, are there some class functions for which a dual turns out to be the complement?

Comment: You can prove (or disprove) your conjecture by constructing a truth table

Comment: In your question, all you did was apply the NOT operator and DeMorgan's. In the case of XOR, since the matrix is symmetric and has exactly half of it as '0' and half as '1' your result is kind of obvious.

Comment: Since I'm not a native English speaker, what do you mean by "_dual_"? Is it [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Generalising_De_Morgan_duality)? Do you mean `(A+B)' = A'B'`? Please add the clarification to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @thebusybee [This page](https://iep.utm.edu/duality-in-logic-and-language/) discusses (in the 1st paragraph) why I dislike seeing the word 'dual' being applied here and in the rest of the page discusses its meaning in the context of logic. It also has meaning in 'functional analysis' and in 'order theory'. And it can mean the 1:1 correspondence between ["algebra" and "geometry."](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/duality+between+algebra+and+geometry) Better to find ***any*** other way to write in English, I think. To avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. But commonly we use this XOR = A ⊕ B = A'B + AB'
is *dual* nothing but the complement of ...?

Here:
In your question, you have done complement twice. *'The XNOR gate is the complement of the XOR gate'* and *'The XNOR gate is the complement of the XOR gate'*.